# How to add sub columns within a main column in angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

I am trying to add sub columns within a main column for my table created with Angular and Bootstrap but I am not able to add sub columns. I am trying to get a table like this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

id Name   Math  Science 
         1 2 3  1 2 3

Some Table like the one in this image:
[image: Some Table like the one in this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with Angular. You can create such a table with just HTML and CSS. Here a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkxmlF5npSE6K5AZs95X?p=preview) for you.

The main idea is to use `colspan` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to let people know that I was working with MEAN. But thanks, that worked. :)